# How to keep authenticated state on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using firebase authentication for my app. I used useAuth hook from [here](https://usehooks.com/useAuth/). Integrate with [react-router guide](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) about redirect (Auth).

`SignIn,SignOut` function is working as expected. But when I try to refresh the page. It redirects to `/login` again.

My expected: Redirect to `/` route when authenticated.

I tried to add this code in PrivateRoute.js

```
  if (auth.loading) {
    return <div>authenticating...</div>;
  }
```

So I can refresh the page without redirect to `/login` but it only show `authenticating...` when click the `log out` button.

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-jennings-j1m1f?file=/src/PrivateRoute.js

What I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Your codesandbox appears to be forever loading/authenticating and makes your issue unreproducible.

Comment: @DrewReese you can check again

Comment: you check the user too soon. you should show loading component while your hook is fetching user info.

Comment: @ducmai how can I wait for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Seems you weren't rendering the "authenticating" loading state quite enough.

I think namely you weren't clearing the `loading` state correctly in the `useEffect` in `useAuth` when the initial auth check was resolving.

## Solution

Set `loading` true whenever initiating an auth check or action, and clear when the check or action completes.

useAuth

```
function useProvideAuth() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // <-- initial true for initial mount render
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  // Wrap any Firebase methods we want to use making sure ...
  // ... to save the user to state.
  const signin = (email, password) => {
    setLoading(true); // <-- loading true when signing in
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response.user);
        return response.user;
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false)); // <-- clear
  };

  const signout = () => {
    setLoading(true); // <-- loading true when signing out
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        setUser(false);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false)); // <-- clear
  };

  // Subscribe to user on mount
  // Because this sets state in the callback it will cause any ...
  // ... component that utilizes this hook to re-render with the ...
  // ... latest auth object.
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(false);
      }
      setLoading(false); // <-- clear
    });

    // Cleanup subscription on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  // Return the user object and auth methods
  return {
    loading,
    user,
    signin,
    signout
  };
}
```

Check the loading state in `PrivateRoute` as you were

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth.loading) return "authenticating";

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-keep-authenticated-state-on-refresh]

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, it works for me :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state
});

function ConnectedApp() {
     const [auth, profile] = useAuth()

     const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

     useEffect(() => {

       if (auth && auth.uid) {
          setIsLoggedIn(true)
       } else {
          setIsLoggedIn(false)
       }
     }, [auth, profile]);

     return (<Router>
       <Redirect to="/app/home"/>
       <div className="App">
       <Switch>

        <Route path="/home"><Home/></Route>
        <Route path="/login"><Login styles={currentStyles}/></Route>
        <Route path="/logout"><Logout styles={currentStyles}/></Route>
        <Route path="/signup" render={isLoggedIn
            ? () => <Redirect to="/app/home"/>
            : () => <Signup styles={currentStyles}/>}/>
        <Route path="/profile" render={isLoggedIn
            ? () => <Profile styles={currentStyles}/>
            : () => <Redirect to="/login"/>}/>

      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>);
    }
const App = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedApp)

export default App;
```

Comment: seem like your useEffect is broken

Comment: Sorry, yes, did not copy the last line, thanks corrected

Comment: I tried by add isLoggedIn state but it's stuck at `/login` route : https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-jennings-j1m1f?file=/src/PrivateRoute.js